# JSON_SEARCH negation in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

whats the MySQL `sql` comand equivalent of this :
`select id where not json_search(example,'one','0')`
it selects only elements where there is no `'0'` in the json array of the column named example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `json_search()` function returns NULL when it finds no match. It does not return `false`. You can't use `NOT` to negate it, because NULL is not false. The negation of `NULL` is still `NULL`.

You can query it this way:

```
select id from ...mytable... 
where json_search(example, 'one', '0') is [not] null;
```

Use `is null` if you want cases where no match is found.

Use `is not null` if you want cases where a match is found.